# Being able to tell the difference between different probability events given scenarios

Tags: probability

State out of the 4 scenarios,which scenario is independent,dependent,mutually exclusive or non-mutually exclusive for each scenario below.

A)Selecting a gift. The first event is that the gift is edible and the second event is that the gift is a book.

B)Sample two members of a family such as a mother and her child. The first event is that the mother has brown hair, and the second event is that the child has brown hair.

C)If one card is selected from a deck of cards, the first event is that the card is a spade and the second event is that the card is a face card.

D)Selecting 2 flowers from different vases. The first event is selecting a tulip from the first vase and the second event is selecting a tulip from the second vase.

my work:

A)Selecting a gift. The first event is that the gift is edible and the second event is that the gift is a book.= mutually exclusive because they have no common outcomes

B)Sample two members of a family such as a mother and her child. The first event is that the mother has brown hair, and the second event is that the child has brown hair.=non-mutually exclusive because they have a common outcome,because both mother and child have brown hair

C)If one card is selected from a deck of cards, the first event is that the card is a spade and the second event is that the card is a face card.=dependent event because changes have occurred

D)Selecting 2 flowers from different vases. The first event is selecting a tulip from the first vase and the second event is selecting a tulip from the second vase.=independent event because the event of the first event has no effect on the second event

Comment: I interpret the problem as asking eight questions.  Is the first scenario an example of mutually exclusive or non-mutually exclusive events?  (*You answered this one*).  Is the first scenario an example of independent or dependent events?  (*You did not answer this one*).  Is the second scenario an example of mutually exclusive or non-mutually exclusive events?  (*You answered this one*).  Is the second scenario an example of independent or dependent events?  (*You did not answer this one*).  Etc...

Comment: As for those questions which you *did* answer, your answer to (C) is incorrect.  To see this, approach by the *definition* of independence and verify that $Pr(A\cap B)$ does in fact in this case equal $Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$ thus implying independence.

Comment: sorry im confused,is C the only one incorrect ,what about A,B,and D?

Comment: A and B are partially correct but are still missing information as to whether or not they are dependent or independent.  The question for D is poorly worded, but under most natural interpretations of the problem I would say that your answer there is also partially correct.  By partially correct, I mean to say that you answered only part of the question but did not answer the full question.

Comment: so since C is an independent event, then D must be dependent, and as per my thinking i would assume A and B are correct?

Comment: The problem statement is not written in such a way as to imply that exactly one of the scenarios is mutually exclusive, that exactly one is non-mutually exclusive, that exactly one is independent, and that exactly one is independent.  Multiple can be independent.  Multiple can be non-mutually exclusive.  Multiple can be dependent, etc...  the events in (A) for instance are *both* mutually exclusive *and* dependent.

Comment: yes I understand,my teacher gave me these scenarios and i was supposed to identify from each scenario(A,B,C,D) Which one is independent,dependent,mutually exclusive and non-mutually exclusive with only that information each scenario

Comment: and her wording made me confused ,because I would like to add on to what you said on the scenarios how their poorly worded

Comment: $\begin{array}{c|c|c}&\text{Mutually exclusive?}&\text{Independent?}\\(A)&Yes&\color{blue}{No}\\(B)&No&\color{blue}{?}\\(C)&\color{blue}{?}&\color{red}{Yes}\\(D)&\color{blue}{?}&Yes\end{array}$  You answered everything in black correctly.  You left out all of those labeled in blue, the first of which I filled in for you.  You got wrong those labeled in red, the correct answer I wrote in its place.

Comment: yes I could see why they could be either,but since their could be only one answer you could only use for each strongly for each senario would you agree with my answer: that for A-mutually exclusive,B-non-mutually exclusive,-C-independent,D-dependent?

Comment: No.  I do not agree that they could only be one answer.  I *vehemently* disagree with that.  There are events which are simultaneously mutually exclusive and dependent.  There are events which are simultaneously non-mutually exclusive and independent.  There are events which are the other combinations (*though simultaneously mutually exclusive and independent are a very special case which I encourage you to look at more closely*).  I do not agree that only one of (C) and (D) can be independent.  They both are independent.

Comment: when my teacher gave me these scenarios she said that i could only use one of terms only once and none can be repeated twice

Comment: Because she made a mistake?  Because she doesn't actually understand probability?  Because she is blindly following along with printed material that she didn't write herself without checking it for correctness?  Because she is cruel and is intentionally misleading students?  I don't know, but if I were you I would ignore what you think you heard about "use each term only once" for this problem entirely

Comment: ok, but which scenario would you think represents dependent

Comment: i understand your point on the independent event as well as mutually exclusive

Comment: Both (A) and (B) are dependent.  Both (C) and (D) are independent.  Only (A) is mutually exclusive.  Each of (B),(C),(D) are non-mutually exclusive (*presumably for D... since we technically weren't told the contents of the vases*).  Incorrectly thinking that (C) is dependent rather than independent is a common mistake, but it is as mentioned *a mistake* and can be proven by just following the actual rigorous mathematical definitions of what it means to be independent and doing the math rather than blindly trusting intuition which has not been properly developed and trained yet.

Comment: ok, and this is my homework question and i'll have to hand this question in ,deciding which scenario represents the terms given above, so since shes my teacher i'll have to follow her instructions so I think for A- i'll put mutually exclusive,and for B -i'll put non-mutually exclusive,and C-independent,and D-dependent events. And it's my teachers first year of teaching and im guessing she doesn't know how to create proficient questions that clearly describe the event being displayed in a situation

Comment: do you think theirs a possibility that D could be non-mutually exclusive and B could be dependent?